# Python-Scrapy : Yielding a Variable name defined in one function through Another

Tags: python, scrapy

After declaring a variable in parse function as "self.Title" and yielding the data through another function, it is returning the data of only one URL across all others.What can be going wrong. Here is the code snippet.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Test'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://example.com/search?q=com.foo', 'https://example.com/search?q=bar', 'https://example.com/search?q=data']

    def parse(self, response):

        self.Title = response.xpath('//*[@class="search-title"]/a/text()')[0].extract()
        Ini_Url = response.xpath('//*[@class="search-title"]/a/@href')[0].extract()
        Ab_url = "https://example.com" + Ini_Url + "/download?from=details"
        yield Request(Ab_url, callback=self.parse_download)

    def parse_download(self, response):
        Download_URL = response.xpath('//*[@class="fdownload-box"]/p[2]/a/@href')[0].extract()

        yield{"Download_URL": Download_URL, "Title": self.Title}
```

And the output is coming like Download_URL are different for all 3 scraped URLs but Title although different are coming same for all 3 request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store per-item data on an instance of the Spider class.

When `parse` yields the `Request`, pass your `Title` as `metadata`, as described in the [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions). It's then available for use in `parse_download` on the `response.meta` property.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply, but considering me as a beginner can you help me on this response.meta property meaning how specifically I can use it in this context.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, I did wrote this snippet in the first function:

```
request.meta['Title'] = Title
yield request
```

And called it into another via :

```
Title = response.meta['Title']
```